# Get super set records not contained in a subset (mutual exclusion)

Tags: sql

I have a `table A`

```
itemid     itemname     itemgroup
  1        item1        group1
  2        item2        group1
  3        item3        group1
```

and a `table B`

```
itemid     itemname     itemgroup     invid
  1        item1        group1          1
  3        item3        group1          1
```

In my case `table B` is a subset of `table A` or `table A` is a superset of `table B` (Its a table of items already inventoried). Is there a way to get a list of records of `group1` from `table A` not present in `table B`? Not sure if there is a set operation to get records from super set not contained in the subset (mutual exclusion)?

Currently I am using the following representational query. Is this the right way of accomplishing this? I am currently working in SQL server, but would appreciate answers pertaining to Oracle and MySQL as well.

```
SELECT itemid, itemname, itemgroup 
  FROM tableA 
 WHERE itemid NOT IN (SELECT itemid 
                        FROM tableB 
                       WHERE invid = parameter)
```

Comment: @OMGPonies edited question. Currently working with SQL server, but would it be possible with Oracle or MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query is OK but you could also do:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b.itemid FROM tableB b WHERE b.itemid = a.itemid 
                       AND b.invid = parameter )
```

You could also do an outer join.

Answer (score 3):

[image: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins]

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       TableA A
LEFT JOIN  TableB B ON A.itemid = B.itemid AND B.invid = parameter
WHERE      B.itemid IS NULL
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: The LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is only more for performant on MySQL, and when the columns compared are not nullable: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ [SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/), [Oracle](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)