# check the likeness between two very large data tables on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, netezza

I need to check the likeness between two data tables on SQL. I am working on Aginity Workbench for Netezza on Win 7.

The tables are very large. One of them has 100 million rows and 4 columns; another one has 1500 million rows and 3 columns.

Example, table1

```
  ID1    ID2      ID3        Value   
  xxxx   xxxxxx   xxxxxxxx    xxx.xxxxxx  // here x is 0-9 int
```

table2:

```
  ID1    ID2          Value   
  xxxx   xxxxxx     xxx.xxxxxx
```

the ID1 and ID2 may be duplicated but Values are not duplicated in the same table.

I need to check whether table1 is a subset of table2 and find the rows that are avaialble in table1 but not in table2 and vice versa.

I am new to SQL. How to design the efficient SQL queries ? I need to do the same tasks frequently, so en efficient query may be more helpful.

**UPDATE**
I used solution at:

[Get super set records not contained in a subset (mutual exclusion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643819/get-super-set-records-not-contained-in-a-subset-mutual-exclusion)

But, the results are 0 rows. I also checked that there are no duplicated rows in the two tables. 
Why table2 is much larger than table1 ?

Are there other ways to find their differences ?

Thanks

Comment: Mysql or SqlServer? Seems unlikely it's both. What have you tried is a question. Also is this a one off task, and every now and then, or something you want to do very frequently?

Comment: What's the part you causing you difficulty?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, I am new to SQL. How to design the efficient SQL queries ? Thanks

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson, please see my new edits. thanks !

Comment: MySql or sql server???? This is two basic outer join queries, after adding a couple of indexes there's not much you can do on the software front. You'd be better off finding a way to avoid doing this at all, frequently would be inadvisable...

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson, Netezza SQL, would you please tell me how to add index for queries ? thanks !

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson, the ID1 and ID2 may be duplicated but Values are not duplicated in the same table.

Comment: I know nothing about Netezza

Answer (score 0):

NETEZZA

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_2
```